# Prolog - unsure about the rules for books

Tags: prolog

I literally dont have a clue what to do about the rules, i hate prolog, all I have done is ,i listed the facts

Use a structured data object to represent a book. The information that describes a
book is:

- Title
- Author
- Genre
- Number of pages

The genre should be one of the following {crime, drama, comedy, study, fiction,
reference}.

You can represent a library as a list of books.
Write a set of rules for recommending a set of books for:

- Holidays (book should be less than 400 pages and not be a study or reference
  book).
- Revision (book that is either for study or a reference book with more than 300
  pages).
- Literary reading (drama books).
- Leisure (books that either comedy or fiction).

facts:

- book(hamlet, shakes, drama, 300)
- book(map, osi, reference, 100)
- book(csi, jerry, crime, 80)
- book(anchorman, ferrel, comedy, 200)
- book(java, jomo, study, 400)
- book(bible , jesus , fiction, 600)

rules: its how to do the rules , is all im asking , for example , for holiday should the code for the first rule be : holidayPages(400,Y) :- book(_, _, Y),400

Comment: What's the question? How to do all of this? You seem to be in need of some basic examples of prolog.

Comment: All of these are pretty straight-forward when you are used to Prolog. I suggest you start with one of the simpler predicates (for example `Literary`) and other simple Prolog examples to sort it out.

Comment: Now I like `book(bible, jesus, fiction, 600).`, lol. Anyway, try `holidays(B) :- B = book(T,A,G,P), P < 400, G \= study, etc...`

Answer (score 3):

chac has already paved the way. Prolog rules have the form:

```
Head :- Body.
```

For the head you can choose a compound or atom. The body can be
a Prolog query. Queries are basically built from:

```
- Invocations: Call some other rules with bound or unbound arguments
- Conditions: Unification =, Arithmetic =:=, <, etc.. Lexical @<, ==, etc..
- Connectives: And ,, Or ;, Not \+ etc..
- Everything else that is found in the handbook of your Prolog system.
```

If you have a verbal spec for rules. First look for the main invocation, 
then for the conditions and finally for the connectives. Here is an example:

```
Holidays (book should be less than 400 pages and not be a study or reference book).
```

I get:

```
Main invocation: book(Title, Author, Genre, Pages)
Condition_1: Pages < 400
Condition_2: Genre = study
Condition_3: Genre = reference
Connectives: Condition_1, \+ (Condition_2 ; Condition_3)
```

If I put all this together I get the following body, which you can easily
first test in the top level as a query:

```
?- book(Title, Author, Genere, Pages), Pages < 400, \+ (Genre = study; Genre = reference).
```

Now you can turn this into a rule. Watch out to use the underscore (_) for
unused invokation variables, otherwise the Prolog systems barks at you with a 
singleton warning:

```
holidays(Title) :- 
     book(Title, _, Genre, Pages), 
     Pages < 400, 
     \+ (Genre = study; Genre = reference).
```

This is a nice homework, you have a good teacher. Have Fun.

Bye